# Add custom value when posting to WebAPI from AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

In an AngularJS app using a Web API as datasource, how would I go about adding custom values to the post?

For example, I have the following input fields, that a user enters:

```
* Name
* Phone
```

But the API post also expects a userId, and some other info, that I need to add, based on various conditions.
How/should I intercept the Post from Angular to the API, to add my own values, or should it be done in the WebAPI controller post method? If so how?

The Factory in Angular:

```
myApp.factory('Product', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('http://api.com/api/products/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
            update: {
                method: 'PUT'
            }
        });
    });
```

in the controller:

```
vm.product = new Product();
vm.save = function() {
            vm.product.$save(
                function(data) {
                    vm.message = "... Save Complete";
                },
                function(response) {
                    vm.message = response.statusText + "\r\n";
                    if (response.data.modelState) {
                        for (var key in response.data.modelState) {
                            vm.message += response.data.modelState[key] + "\r\n";
                        }
                    }
                    if (response.data.exceptionMessage)
                        vm.message += response.data.exceptionMessage;
                });
        };
```

Should it be done in the Angular app or the Web API?

Comment: There is nothing to intercept. Angular never posts stuff by itself. Your own code, in the controller, decides what and when to post.

Comment: The API should be the most logical as it can. For example, the ID of a resource is typically generated at server-side. So asking an ID when creating a resource is not a good idea: what could the client possibly sent? What's the point of sending an ID if the server discards it and generates its own? On the contrary, if some information is mandatory to create a user (let's say its birth date), and the client doesn't send any, the server can't guess what the birth date is, so obviously, it needs to come from the client. Not sure if that answers the question.

Comment: In my simple app, the user is logged in. the login is also handled by WebAPI and stanrd ASP auth. The user gets a UserID. This UserID needs to be associated with everything he posts. This is one example.

Another one is, that in the above example, the user only enters Name and Phone number. But i also want to set the status of the product to, lets say and int of 1. This has to happen everytime a user enters a new product, but they are not allowed to select the status them selves intitialy, so there i need to set if "for them". Makes sense?

Comment: If the status is always 1 and can't be anything else when creating a product, I wouldn't force the client to send it.

Comment: So again; where should i set the values so it gets saved in the database? In the client (Angular) or in the Web API? And how would this code look. Example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If it's not in the client, where could it be? I don't know anything about .Net, but I guess you can do something like `product.status = 1;` on the server.